# Server 415 Response code

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jax-rs, http-request

I am using Jetty web server, and Jersey for REST handling.

I defined:

```
@POST
@Path("/sendMessage")
@Consumes ({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public Response sendMessage(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo) 
{
    logger.debug("sendMessage:");
    System.out.println("Received POST!");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();

}
```

However, when I send a http request, `http://localhost:8080/hqsim/sendMessage`, the server returns a 415 code.

It's like the call is not allowed. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

415 means that the media type is unsupported. 
The most likely case is that you are either missing the `Content-Type` header in your request, or it's incorrect. In your case it must be `application/xml` or `text/xml`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using axios, and making;

a) A post request, you should define the request as below

```
await axios.post("the url you're speaking to",
     {the data to post}, 
     {
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
     })
```

b) A get request;

```
await axios.get("the url you're speaking to",
     {
        data: {},
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        params: {'varX': '34'}
     })
```

where varX is the name of the variable you're sending together with the request
params can as well be empty if you're not sending a query string along.

the url would therefore appear as;

```
https://myurl.com/?varX=34
```